# Quasar v2 vue 3 and electron access pinia store from electron preload script to use data in a child window

Tags: electron, vuejs3, quasar-framework

I am working on a Quasar v2 Vue 3 application with electron mode enabled. I have a child window that needs data from my pinia store but I have no idea how to access the pinia store from my preload script.

I have imported my store into the preload script like I would any other component but when I run my app I get an error asking if I have installed pinia...

this is an example of my code that I've been working with

```
import { contextBridge, ipcRenderer } from 'electron';
import { usePrinter } from 'src/stores/printStore';

const printerStore = usePrinter();

window.printStore = printerStore;
contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('hiAPI', {
    downloadFiles: (payload: any) => ipcRenderer.invoke('download-files', payload),
    downloadFile: (payload: any) => ipcRenderer.invoke('download-file', payload),
    displayMessage: (channel: string, func : any) => ipcRenderer.on(channel, func),
    hiDetailReport: (payload: any) =>
        ipcRenderer.invoke('detail-report', payload),
    openDevTools: () => ipcRenderer.invoke('openDevTools'),
    printToPdf: () => ipcRenderer.invoke('printToPdf'),
});
```

that is what I have so far but again it gives the is pinia installed error..

Is there any way to get this to work?
I am using Typescript

what else can I do to get the data to my child window?

any help or insights would be greatfull.
thank you

Comment: Can you please provide the *exact* error you get, with the stack and all?